# C++ Implicit conversion

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {


    char x = 'a';
    char y = 'b';
    char z = x + y;
        printf("%d\n",z);
    return 0;
}
```

Why is the output of this code -61?

Comment: Why are you printing a `char` as a digit/number?

Comment: And why are you using `printf` after including `<iostream>` ?

Comment: and `printf` does not belong to `iostream`

Comment: Also, you should turn up your warning.  You should get something like *warning: conversion to 'char' from 'int' may alter its value [-Wconversion]* letting you know what you are doing is suspect.

Comment: @NathanOliver: How so? `%d` expects an `int`, and `z` is promoted to one. Now, `x+y` looks like it overflows, which **is** undefined behavior.

Comment: @MSalters Oops, you're right.  forgot about the promotion

Comment: What do you expect and why? Your title suggests that you already know that something fishy is going on, but it is not clear what you actually want to do

Comment: (To be exact - `x+y` likely does not overflow itself, as the arguments are promoted to `int` prior to addition, but assigning the result to `z` would overflow)

Comment: Why negative rating? Yes, it's an beginner question. But IMHO not a bad one.

Answer (score 0):

a)
Every char is in the computer a number. (a computer can only handle numbers, characters are "only" images for a computer.)

So: search for the ASCII table. e.g. http://www.asciitable.com/

-> a=97, b=98

a+b=97 + 98 = 195

b)
char is defined as 8 bit (=256 numbers) with sign: It can contain the numbers between -128 and 127. So 195 did not fit. When calculating this, the carry was thrown away, and such a number appears.

Edit:

To show, whats internally happen: The calculation as binary:

```
 0110 0001 ('a' = 97)
+0110 0010 ('b' = 98)
 ---------
 1100 0011
```

Because this is a signed number, this is stored [two complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)).
First bis is set -> negative. But the most easy way (for me) to calc:

This first bit has the value of -128, the second of 64.
the least bits: 2 and 1. So:-128 + 64 + 2 + 1 = -61

hopes this helps more than this is confusing...

Edit 2:

As result of the discussion: This is what happens on your CPU. This is because the CPU has some technical parameter. But you can not assume, that this happens on every CPU! C++ compiles on / for every CPU, but an overflow is not defined in C/C++, so on other CPUs there can be other results.

Comment: No, overflowing is UB not modular arithmetic

Comment: Yes, it's undefined for C++ specs. But this is what the CPU does. And that was the question "Why -61?"

Comment: No, what the CPU does has nothing to do with whether this is defined. Its UB for a reason. Your answer implies this is defined behaviour, which is to say the least, misleading.

Comment: My answer did not say this is correct / defined behavior (in C++). My answer said what happens on the metal - and this is defined!